# GuzzleHttp - Host is blocked

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics-api, guzzle

I am installing on my web space the Google API PHP client (2.1.0) and [following this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php#helloanalyticsphp). The problem is when I go to `HelloAnalytics.php` I have a PHP error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException' with message 'cURL error
>   6: See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html' in
>   /reporting_com/google-api-php-client-2.1.0_PHP54/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlFactory.php:126
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /reporting_com/google-api-php-client-2.1.0_PHP54/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlFactory.php(91): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlFactory::createErrorResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlMultiHandler),
>   Array, Array) #1
>   /reporting_com/google-api-php-client-2.1.0_PHP54/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlMultiHandler.php(244): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlFactory::createResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlMultiHandler),
>   Array, Array, Array, Resource id #128) #2 /share/src_serv-prd in
>   /reporting_com/google-api-php-client-2.1.0_PHP54/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php
>   on line 49

The 6th error on the libcurl-errors.html page of GuzzleHttp website say :

> CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6)
>   Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved.

And that seems legit: I am on my company network which blocks every curl host. I have to say to my sysadmin to unlock this host in order to allow Curl to work but I don't manage to find the URL host.

What is it?

Comment: Did you set a custom user agent in your curl request?

Comment: Try setting the user agent to `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36` or whatever browser is allowed by your network, and it should pass just fine.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the user agent. its simply that you connected using a domain name, not an IP, and the DNS used by curl didn't recognize that domain name, so it did not know what IP to connect to. either specify your company's internal DNS server with CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4 / CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP6 , or specify the IP directly with CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm 100% sure it's not about user agent but the host to enable in our network (it's not the first time I use Curl and everytime i have to ask to my sysadmin to unlock used hosts). @hanshenrik I dont make a curl connect by myself, I use the Google Analytics PHP Api code -> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php#helloanalyticsphp

Comment: If i make "var_dump($options)" in the guzzlehttp\ringphp\src\Client\CurlFactory.php ($options are parameters used within curl_setopt_array() ) , i get an array with at the beginning "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts". Is "googleapis.com" the host i need to unlock to get curl working ?

Comment: Paolito75: Have you already solved this problem? I ran today into same error with analytics PHP API and can't solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

To continue other request you can set options **http_errors** to false:

```
$option = [ 
            ....   
            'http_errors' => false,
            ...
        ];
```